# A low price given to a new costumer is called "the get-acquainted price"?

Tags: terminology

It is very often to see, especially in Wholesaling (but not only), a low price that is given to a new customer, in order that he will get acquainted with their product.

What is the term used to describe this specific special price?

I have tried to look for the name of this price, and I found very few results for "the get-acquainted price".

Answer (score 2):

"**New customer pricing**" is special pricing for new customers only. Existing customers cannot normally get this price.

In particular, communications service companies have these special prices. Sometimes it's an introductory price that goes up 3-6 months after joining, but other times it's a permanent lower price just for new customers, and existing customers have to keep paying their higher price.

Comment: You can also call it an [introductory price](https://competera.net/resources/articles/introductory-pricing#:~:text=or%20Penetration%20pricing.-,What%20is%20Introductory%20pricing%3F,audience%20for%20the%20new%20entry.(https://competera.net/resources/articles/introductory-)pricing#:~:text=or%20Penetration%20pricing.-,What%20is%20Introductory%20pricing%3F,audience%20for%20the%20new%20entry.)

Comment: @KateBunting Disagree. "Introductory price" is the price for a new product hitting the market, in contrast with the price it will eventually settle at. An introductory price doesn't discriminate in favour of new customers over existing ones.

Comment: OK - I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If an item is sold at a loss (at a price lower than the seller's cost for it), then it is often called a "[loss leader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_leader)". For example, a grocer might place apples near the store's entrance and advertise a very low price for them. The grocer will lose money on the apples, but once the customer is inside the store, he or she is likely to buy other items, so the grocer will make money overall.

If the item is not sold at a loss, then "loss leader" wouldn't technically apply, but some people might call it that anyway due to the lack of any other term for the practice (at least as far as I'm aware).